# Android stock browser ignores meta viewport

Tags: android, html, css, viewport, meta

I am experiencing some issues with a website I am trying to build. I did some research (like always) among this and other websites (as usual) and like never, I was not able to find a solution that worked for me. Please have patience with me since I am a beginner (developing for practice and learn purposes).
So here's the deal. I started building a website but I got stuck in making it responsive. After the research I was talking about earlier I used the

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

It works as long as I am accesing the website throught the Chrome Browser for Android. It also works in Chrome for Windows when I select the mobile view or resize the window. The only browser that acts like skipping that meta line is the stock Samsung Browser (WebKit - it think, though not sure about the name).
Is there anyone that experiences the same thing? I was thinking is only my phone (Galaxy S2) but it seems that I am not the only one with this issue.

Thanks in advance and looking forword for a solution.

**LATER EDIT**

Worked around with the values. Seems like the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">` is actually not ignored.
I played around with the max zoom values and it seems to work. The only issue now is that the stock android browser does not display the page acording to the `@media screen and (max-width: 640px)` present in the stylesheet file...

**LATER (FINAL) EDIT**

The css code was somehow faulty. Deleted the multiple screen resolution support and worked around only with the normal web view, then added support only for one resolution (`@media screen and (max-width: 500px)`) seemed to work (anyway, there are just a few devices out there that has width lower than 500). Now in regular view, the site successfully shows the content according to the CSS file. Shrinking the resolution will also display the page in a correct manner. I also noticed, that using "max-width" should be done in ascending order (first deal with high resolutions resolutions first).

Comment: you're missing a comma in your meta tag (initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0,) - maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Nope. First i tried only with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>. Did not worked. I tested also with the forgoten coma. Still same thing.